# Cakephp - unable to update boolean to true?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

This works:
($this->Task->save('active', '0')

This does not:
($this->Task->save('active', '1')

it fails model validation:
Model->Task

```
'active' => array(
    'boolean' => array(
    'rule' => array('boolean'),
    ),
),
```

TaskController.php

This works:

```
public function deactivate ($id = null) {
    $this->Task->id = $id;
    if (!$this->Task->exists()) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid task'));
    }
    $this->request->onlyAllow('post');
    if ($this->Task->save('active', '0')) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('The task has been saved'));
        $this->redirect($this->referer());
    } else {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('The task could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
```

This does not:

```
public function activate ($id = null) {  
    $this->Task->id = $id;  
    if (!$this->Task->exists()) {  
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid task'));  
    }    
    $this->request->onlyAllow('post');    
    if ($this->Task->save('active', 1)) {  
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('The task has been saved'));  
    $this->redirect($this->referer());  
   } else {  
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('The task could not be saved. Please, try again.'));  
    $this->redirect($this->referer());  
   }  
}
```

Here is the call from View/Tasks/index.ctp:

```
<?php 
     if ($task['Task']['active'] == 1){
        echo $this->Form->postLink(__('Deactivate'), array('action' => 'deactivate', $task['Task']['id']),null, __('Are you sure you want to return # %s to the project?', $task['Task']['id']));
    } else {
        echo $this->Form->postLink(__('Activate'), array('action' => 'activate', $task['Task']['id']),null, __('Are you sure you want to send # %s to your todo list?', $task['Task']['id']));
    }
  ?>
```

mysql db: field 'active' is type "tinyint".

Also, the checkbox form control generated by Bake in Views/Tasks/edit.ctp works just fine.

I have also tried the following:

```
 ($this->Task->save('active', 1)
 ($this->Task->save('active', true)
 ($this->Task->save('active', 'true')
 ($this->Task->save('active', '2')
```

This:

```
 ($this->Task->save('active', `1`) //notice the tic marks
```

seems to bypass validation, but does not update the database.

Comment: can u post ur sql of this table ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This works: ($this->Task->save('active', '0')

Well, I doubt it :)

It might not give an error but it's not going to do what you expect. That's going to skip validating and try to process `'active'` as an array. The consequence of doing that is it's probably *only* bumping the `modified` field time.

> This does not: ($this->Task->save('active', '1')

That's dependent on your validation rules, but regardless that syntax is not going to do what you're expecting.

### Model::save(array $data = null, boolean $validate = true, array $fieldList = array())]

Please refer to [the documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-save-array-data-null-boolean-validate-true-array-fieldlist-array), your parameters are wrong. You're passing the string "active" as your data, and your boolean-ish value as the value of `$validate`.

This would work (or, not fail as being syntactically wrong):

```
$this->Task->save(array('active' => $value));
```

or this:

```
$this->Task->save(array('Task' => array('active' => $value)));
```

or by using saveField:

```
$this->Task->saveField('active', $value)
```

If in doubt - [use bake](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/code-generation-with-bake.html), or compare to the code it generates.

Comment: saveField did the trick.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you just follow the documentation?
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-savefield-string-fieldname-string-fieldvalue-validate-false

There it clearly shows that you are misusing save().

You would need to use saveField() or updateAll() (atomic) for what you are doing.

Comment: You could do without the condescending preamble "Why dont you just follow the documentation?". I would never have asked the question if i had not beat me head against the wall for hours. I will admit it was a boneheaded mistake, but still one I needed help with.

Comment: Just saying: Your first look should be into the docs, then you should try to ask for help. Glad you figured it out.